# Python Multiprocessing Logging via QueueHandler

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have a Python multiprocessing application to which I would like to add some logging functionality.
The [Python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) recommends using a `Queue`. Every process will put log records into it via the `QueueHandler` and a Listener Process will handle the records via a predefined `Handler`.

Here is the example provided by the Python logging cookbook:

```
# You'll need these imports in your own code
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing

# Next two import lines for this demo only
from random import choice, random
import time

#
# Because you'll want to define the logging configurations for listener and workers, the
# listener and worker process functions take a configurer parameter which is a callable
# for configuring logging for that process. These functions are also passed the queue,
# which they use for communication.
#
# In practice, you can configure the listener however you want, but note that in this
# simple example, the listener does not apply level or filter logic to received records.
# In practice, you would probably want to do this logic in the worker processes, to avoid
# sending events which would be filtered out between processes.
#
# The size of the rotated files is made small so you can see the results easily.
def listener_configurer():
    root = logging.getLogger()
    h = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('mptest.log', 'a', 300, 10)
    f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    h.setFormatter(f)
    root.addHandler(h)

# This is the listener process top-level loop: wait for logging events
# (LogRecords)on the queue and handle them, quit when you get a None for a
# LogRecord.
def listener_process(queue, configurer):
    configurer()
    while True:
        try:
            record = queue.get()
            if record is None:  # We send this as a sentinel to tell the listener to quit.
                break
            logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
            logger.handle(record)  # No level or filter logic applied - just do it!
        except Exception:
            import sys, traceback
            print('Whoops! Problem:', file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)

# Arrays used for random selections in this demo

LEVELS = [logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING,
          logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL]

LOGGERS = ['a.b.c', 'd.e.f']

MESSAGES = [
    'Random message #1',
    'Random message #2',
    'Random message #3',
]

# The worker configuration is done at the start of the worker process run.
# Note that on Windows you can't rely on fork semantics, so each process
# will run the logging configuration code when it starts.
def worker_configurer(queue):
    h = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)  # Just the one handler needed
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)
    # send all messages, for demo; no other level or filter logic applied.
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# This is the worker process top-level loop, which just logs ten events with
# random intervening delays before terminating.
# The print messages are just so you know it's doing something!
def worker_process(queue, configurer):
    configurer(queue)
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print('Worker started: %s' % name)
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(random())
        logger = logging.getLogger(choice(LOGGERS))
        level = choice(LEVELS)
        message = choice(MESSAGES)
        logger.log(level, message)
    print('Worker finished: %s' % name)

# Here's where the demo gets orchestrated. Create the queue, create and start
# the listener, create ten workers and start them, wait for them to finish,
# then send a None to the queue to tell the listener to finish.
def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
    listener = multiprocessing.Process(target=listener_process,
                                       args=(queue, listener_configurer))
    listener.start()
    workers = []
    for i in range(10):
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process,
                                         args=(queue, worker_configurer))
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
    queue.put_nowait(None)
    listener.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My question: The example from the Python logging cookbook implies that the `Queue` has to be passed to every function that will be executed in multiprocessing mode. This sure works if you have a small application, but it gets ugly if you have a bigger programm. Is there a way to use something like a Singleton Queue that is created once via `logging.config.dictConfig` and then shared by all processes without having to pass it to every function?

Comment: The multiprocessing module is very flexible. How do you call your multiprocessing function? Do you use the pool, your own process? Can you add a minimal code example?

Comment: I added the example form the Python logging cookbook

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case a few simple classes will do the trick.

Have a look and let me know if you need some further explanations or want something different.

```py
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.pool

from random import choice, random
import time


class ProcessLogger(multiprocessing.Process):
    _global_process_logger = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)

    @classmethod
    def get_global_logger(cls):
        if cls._global_process_logger is not None:
            return cls._global_process_logger
        raise Exception("No global process logger exists.")

    @classmethod
    def create_global_logger(cls):
        cls._global_process_logger = ProcessLogger()
        return cls._global_process_logger

    @staticmethod
    def configure():
        root = logging.getLogger()
        h = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('mptest.log', 'a', 1024**2, 10)
        f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
        h.setFormatter(f)
        root.addHandler(h)

    def stop(self):
        self.queue.put_nowait(None)

    def run(self):
        self.configure()
        while True:
            try:
                record = self.queue.get()
                if record is None:
                    break
                logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
                logger.handle(record)
            except Exception:
                import sys, traceback
                print('Whoops! Problem:', file=sys.stderr)
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)

    def new_process(self, target, args=[], kwargs={}):
        return ProcessWithLogging(self, target, args, kwargs)


def configure_new_process(log_process_queue):
    h = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_process_queue)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class ProcessWithLogging(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, args=[], kwargs={}, log_process=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        if log_process is None:
            log_process = ProcessLogger.get_global_logger()
        self.log_process_queue = log_process.queue

    def run(self):
        configure_new_process(self.log_process_queue)
        self.target(*self.args, **self.kwargs)


class PoolWithLogging(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, processes=None, context=None, log_process=None):
        if log_process is None:
            log_process = ProcessLogger.get_global_logger()
        super().__init__(processes=processes, initializer=configure_new_process,
                         initargs=(log_process.queue,), context=context)


LEVELS = [logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL]
LOGGERS = ['a.b.c', 'd.e.f']
MESSAGES = [
    'Random message #1',
    'Random message #2',
    'Random message #3',
]


def worker_process(param=None):
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print('Worker started: %s' % name)
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(random())
        logger = logging.getLogger(choice(LOGGERS))
        level = choice(LEVELS)
        message = choice(MESSAGES)
        logger.log(level, message)
    print('Worker finished: {}, param: {}'.format(name, param))
    return param


def main():
    process_logger = ProcessLogger.create_global_logger()
    process_logger.start()

    workers = []
    for i in range(10):
        worker = ProcessWithLogging(worker_process)
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()
    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    with PoolWithLogging(processes=4) as pool:
        print(pool.map(worker_process, range(8)))


    process_logger.stop()
    process_logger.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks great! Do you have any suggestions for the scenario of starting the worker processes via the pool?

Comment: See my edited answer. Let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!! Is there a way to make it work under Windows as well? Right now, there is a pickle problem on Windows: `TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Annamaria. I have edited my answer, it should now run on windows. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you!! This is perfect!

Comment: If I try to log in the main process, by adding after `process_logger.start()`
`configure_new_process(process_logger.queue)`    `logger = logging.getLogger(choice(LOGGERS))` `logger.info("Main process log")`
I get duplicated log messages from the workers.
Any idea why ?

Comment: @jul I tried to reproduce your problem. For me it seems to work. Here is the code I used https://pastebin.com/nGZiivAM Here the output I get https://pastebin.com/7DKAqyZR No duplicates, as far as I can tell. I used Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Chris Every messages is duplicated with the exact same code. I use Ubuntu, and that is probably related to how processes are started (by default "spawn" on Windows and "fork" on Linux).

Comment: I found a good explanation [here](https://medium.com/@jonathonbao/python3-logging-with-multiprocessing-f51f460b8778).

Comment: @jul I am glad you found this. This indeed explains it and is related to Windows using spawn and Linux using fork. When using fork the subprocess inherits all the objects and with that reuses the handler on the root logger of the main process. Thus messages are written twice.